# SQL dividing numbers by different group by results

Tags: mysql

Basically I have a table with several columns but I'm only interested in 4. My table looks like this:

```
accountID productID profit cost date       country     city   quantity
        2        10     25   15 2017/03/13 Afghanistan Kabul       330
       18         3     45   42 2017/05/14 UK          London     5300
       25        14     22   17 2017/05/21 UK          London      300
        3        11     30   26 2017/04/23 Afghanistan Herat       400
```

What I want to achieve is to get the total quantity of products by city, by country and the ratio of city_quantity/country_quantity:

```
 country     city    city_quantity country_quantity   city_percentage
Afghanistan Kabul        800            1400              0.57 
Afghanistan Kandahar     400            1400              0.29
Afghanistan Herat        200            1400              0.14
UK        London         6500           10000             0.65
UK        Manchester     3000           10000             0.3
UK        Newcastle       500           10000             0.05
```

So far my script looks like this:

```
select country, city, sum(quantity)
from table
where date > dateadd(month,-1,getdate())
group by country, city
order by country, city
```

The where condition is because I only want the last month of data so consider it irrelevant.

How can I achieve what I want with a simple script?

Comment: I think you show us data from the original table.

Comment: I can see no correlation between the data set and the desired result. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I obviously don't have only the rows that I provide on my original table. It's also my first question on Stack Overflow, so please bear with me.  I just created some rows for the shake of better describing what I want, because the data I have to deal with is let's say quite confidential. But anyway according  to my "original table" how can I get the total quantity per city, total quantity per country and the ratio between those two? Let's say according to my data I should have 3 rows:UK London 5700 5700 1, Afghanistan Kabul 330 730 0.45 and Afghanistan Herat 400 730 0.55

Comment: Perhaps you misread the linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a self-join to sum the quantity grouped by country and then use that value to come up with the percentage like so:

```
CREATE TABLE testTable (country VARCHAR(2), city CHAR(1), quantity DECIMAL(10,2));

INSERT INTO testTable (country, city, quantity)
VALUES
('Af', 'K', 330),
('Af', 'H', 400),
('Af', 'Q', 700),
('UK', 'L', 1000),
('UK', 'M', 500);

SELECT t.country, t.city, t.quantity AS city_quantity, q.qty AS country_quantity, 
       CAST(t.quantity / q.qty AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS city_percentage
FROM testTable t
JOIN
(
  SELECT z.country, SUM(z.quantity) qty
  FROM testTable z
  GROUP BY z.country
) q ON t.country = q.country
```

This will give you the desired results set:

```
+---------+------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| country | city | city_quantity| country_quantity| city_percentage |
+---------+------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Af      | K    |          330 |            1430 | 0.23            |
| Af      | H    |          400 |            1430 | 0.28            |
| Af      | Q    |          700 |            1430 | 0.49            |
| UK      | L    |         1000 |            1500 | 0.67            |
| UK      | M    |          500 |            1500 | 0.33            |
+---------+------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Keep in mind that you'll want to check for division by zero in any production query.

Comment: Thanks, this was actually quite helpful! I got the results I wanted by using a join and two different group bys.